# Does ICommand always requires an object as a parameter?

Tags: mvvm, icommand, relaycommand

When I implement the `ICommand` interface, the following methods are created

```
#region ICommand Members

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
    }

#endregion
```

The interesting part is

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
}
```

Simply because it indicates that it expects 1 parameter. What if I don't need to pass a parameter? In my ViewModel I have the following code

```
public class DownloadViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ICommand BrowseForFile { get; set; }

    public string File { get; set; }

    public DownloadViewModel()
    {
        BrowseForFile = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(OpenDialog));
    }

    private void OpenDialog(object o)
    {
        var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        File = dialog.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```

The `OpenDialog` method does not require the parameter but it appears as if I have to just so I can satisfy the Interface.

Am I doing this right or have I missed the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `ICommand` always needs an object and `RelayCommand` too. If you don't need it, you pass null and don't use it in your method, which is ugly.

I would use Prism's `DelegateCommand` instead. This exists in a non-generic version, which doesn't take parameters:

```cs
Command = new DelegateCommand(DoSomething);
CommandWithParameter = new DelegateCommand<int>(DoSOmethingWithInt);
```

Its in the PRISM assembly, which you have to download and reference.

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism;
```

[PRISM](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/)

Alternatively, use the MVVMLight toolkit, which provides a command class which does basically the same thing. There is no point in using MVVM without a MVVM framework anyway. I can recommend PRISM, also for it's basic stuff like the `DelegateCommand` or the `EventAggregator`.

Comment: I think the point of the question was, does ``OpenDialog`` require a parameter

Comment: I understood the question as "How can I get rid of the parameter in a command action, if I don't need it?"

Comment: Interesting.  The question does appear somewhat ambiguous.  I got the feeling the OP was confused and thinking that ``OpenDialog`` was the implementation of ``Execute`` rather than just called by it.

Comment: @Scroog1 and Marc - sorry for the lack of clarity in the question but thank you both. The question was, am I forced to pass a parameter even if I don't need it. Although Prism/MVVVM light may be an answer, for the moment I need to learn the basics so will continue with the ugly approach! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that `Execute` takes a parameter is irrelevant to the method from your `ViewModel`.  The only thing that affects what parameters `OpenDialog` needs is your implementation of `ICommand`.

If your implementation is, for example:

```cs
public class MyRandomCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _action;

    public MyRandomCommand(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action();
    }

    ...
}
```

Then no parameters will be required for your `OpenDialog` method, as you can create a command as follows:

```cs
public ICommand Command { get { return new MyRandomCommand(OpenDialog); } }
```

You can, however, require any signature you like for the method you are passing to your command.

The most common, off-the-shelf implementations of `RelayCommand` can take methods with either 0 or 1 parameter and will be called from `Execute` appropriately.